# Mount Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller in CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, drivers, automounting

I have an in-built card reader that works fine under Windows, but in Linux, I cannot mount the drive whatever I do.

lspci doesn't show the device
lsusb shows

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

lsblk didn't show anything, so I did
modprobe mmc_block

now lsblk shows

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   200M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0   863G  0 part /media/Windows7_OS
├─sda3                      8:3    0  19.5G  0 part 
├─sda4                      8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5                      8:5    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda6                      8:6    0  48.3G  0 part 
  ├─vg_the-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  40.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_the-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

tried to mount:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sr0 /media/sdcard/
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

dmesg shows:

```
usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129
usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1.4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Generic
usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
usb 1-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

but this doesn't change if I remove or insert a card.

Comment: After hours of googling I found the solution.

I installed kmod-rts5139-1.04-3.el6.elrepo

after that, I had to do sudo modprobe rts5139 and the card reader started working.

But I feel someone might profit from this Q+A, because it is not so obvious, therefore I am leaving it here.

Comment: Can you add that as an actual answer and then accept it? This will make it cleared to others that your problem had a eventual solution and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I installed `kmod-rts5139-1.04-3.el6.elrepo`, and then ran `sudo modprobe rts5139` and the card reader started working.

Comment: In my case using Centos6.5, I did `yum search` and couldn't find the package, so I got it from [here](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/elrepo/elrepo/el6/x86_64/RPMS/kmod-rts5139-1.04-3.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm).